# Change format of all logger instances

Tags: python, python-logging

I need to standardize logging format for multiple Python scripts.

I've written a custom handler; a handler is required rather than a custom format string, since I need to perform additional processing.

```py
import logging


class CustomHandler(logging.Handler):

    def emit(self, record: logging.Record):
        # ...
        pass
```

Which I've assigned to my default logger

```py
handler = CustomHandler()
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
```

I want to **force** all packages (`fastapi`, `scrapy`, `pytest`, etc...) to use this handler as well. I am aware this is not good practice. It is what I would like to do.

I have tried re-assigning the handlers of all child loggers from `logging.root`

```py
def bind():
    for logger in logging.root.manager.loggerDict.values():
        if isinstance(logger, logging.PlaceHolder):
            continue
        logger.handlers = [handler]
```

This has several drawbacks:

1. Messages logged before `bind()` is called appear in whatever format was defined by the package. One would think this could be solved by importing and running it at the very start, but some processes like `uvicorn` (FastAPI) invoke your code as a subprocess.
2. `pytest` appears to define its own custom `master` logging instance (something which `logging` advises against). This means I cannot reset its handlers in the same way

I've read parts of the documentation and looked through the source, but haven't seen a neat solution. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html) is info how to customize pytest logs. [Here](https://medium.com/1mgofficial/how-to-override-uvicorn-logger-in-fastapi-using-loguru-124133cdcd4e) is article about `uvicorn` logs. Do you want to create common handler for all tools? Even if it possible it will be a huge pain to support it and keep compatibility with all tools at same time ([god object detected?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)).

Comment: Just an idea: `pytest` allows to set log format via command line parameter (`pytest --log-format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s"`). Uvicorn also accepting this [option](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#logging). So you may try to create custom log handler that will print something liike `%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s` if called via cmd and run `pytest --log-format="$(print_custom_log_format.py)"` to set custom log. In other cases `CustomHandler` class will be used (in case of `uvicorn` for example). The question is too wide to do exact solution

Comment: @rzlvmp thanks for the links, I'll investigate. God object absolutely in creation, but I'm not the scrum master on this one. I've already seen the custom format options, but note my comment about having to use a `Handler` object for extra processing!

Comment: You should not duplicate your handler. If you are using propagation and adding your handler to the root logger all logs will go through it (if they have a high enough level).